# COM obj error: though DTC is configured

Tags: c#

I have some c# code that is using

```
 using (TransactionScope ts =
                new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                    new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
            {

...

                ts.Complete();
            }
```

I get the following error. Do you have an idea why?

> Server Error in '/MyApp' Application.
>
> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error
>   HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned
>   from a call to a COM component.]
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ReceiveTransaction(UInt32
>   propgationTokenSize, Byte[] propgationToken, IntPtr managedIdentifier,
>   Guid& transactionIdentifier, OletxTransactionIsolationLevel&
>   isolationLevel, ITransactionShim& transactionShim) +0
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[]
>   propagationToken) +384
>
> [TransactionManagerCommunicationException: Communication with the
>   underlying transaction manager has failed.]
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[]
>   propagationToken) +259971
>   System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction
>   tx) +209
>   System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction
>   tx) +339
>   System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Promote(InternalTransaction tx)
>   +21    System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote() +60    System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction
>   transaction) +71
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction
>   transaction, Byte[] whereabouts) +309
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.GetTransactionCookie(Transaction
>   transaction, Byte[] whereAbouts) +45
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction
>   tx) +630
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction
>   transaction) +45
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +1466
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) +84
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +1645767
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +258

Comment: Awesome exception message, detailed and saying nothing.  E_FAIL sucks, doesn't mean anything more than "couldn't do it, don't know why".  And a major reason everybody uses Java instead of COM+.  You'll need Microsoft support if tinkering with config or a magic SO post doesn't solve it.

Comment: If you have firewall enabled, make sure it's configured for MSDTC use. If that's not it, a reinstall of MSDTC, as user9... suggests, will sometimes magically fix it.

Answer (score 0):

[TransactionManagerCommunicationException: Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed.] - This suggests MSDTC is either not installed or is not properly working. Can you try installing/reinstalling MSDTC and enable it.